# In C# how do I create an extension method that takes a lambda with generic parameters, Func<T, TResult> as a parameter.

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, generic-type-argument, extension-function

I'm trying to create an extension method that takes a Func as a parameter but I'm getting an error. Here's what I got:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static TResult ModifyString<T, TResult>(this string s, Func<T, TResult> f)
    {
        return f(s);
    }
}
```

on the `return f(s);` line I get an error: `Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'T'`

How can I specify a generic lambda Func with a generic parameter `T` and a generic return type `TResult`?

Comment: You specified the lambda correctly. The problem is that its parameter is type `T` and you are passing it a string, but the compiler doesn't have any general way to convert string to "absolutely any type at all", which is what `T` can be.

Comment: Replace T with a string class or provide a concept like "where T: string"

Comment: Clearly, you want `f` to be a function that acts on a string. What you want would appear to be `TResult ModifyString<TResult>(this string s, Func<string, TResult> f) => f(s);`. Either that, or `TResult ModifyString<T, TResult>(this T t, Func<T, TResult> f) => f(t);`

Comment: @KirillKorolev: You can't do `where T : sealedtype`.   `where T : string` is the same as "T must always be string", so why have T at all?

Comment: @EricLippert Yeah, that's why I was curious, why does he need a template parameter.

Comment: @KirillKorolev I was asked how to do this in a phone interview, but I may have misremembered the exact question. I thought the parameter to the lambda had to be generic (I could've sworn the interviewer wrote something like Func<TInput, TResult>), but I must've remembered wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the other answer and](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50418914/712649) [comments suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50418807/in-c-sharp-how-do-i-create-an-extension-method-that-takes-a-lambda-with-generic/50419591#comment87853273_50418807), you already know the parameter type `T`, so you only need to specify `TResult`:

```
public static TResult ModifyString<TResult>(this string s, Func<string, TResult> f)
{
    return f(s);
}
```

or consistently pass `T`:

```
public static TResult Modify<T, TResult>(this T s, Func<T, TResult> f)
{
    return f(s);
}
```

Comment: For some reason I thought my interviewer had the extension method be specifically for a string (or some other concrete type) while the lambda had to take a generic parameter, but now I think I remembered that wrong and the lambda must take a string specifically. Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are passing "s" - a string into the func which is declared as taking in type "T".

Change the func to take in a string instead of T, and return a string to make this code work with strings.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string ModifyString(this string s, Func<string, string> f)
    {
        return f(s);
    }
}
```

Assuming you just want a string result.

Comment: I can't imagine what "modify string" means other than this ([for whatever my imagination is worth](http://www.shakespeare-online.com/quickquotes/quickquotehamletdreamt.html)).

Comment: @EdPlunkett me neither, but it is still an assumption

Comment: @EdPlunkett It's just a pointless example. I was asked if I could create an extension method (nope) that takes in a string (I think) and a generic lambda that operates on the string and returns something.

Comment: @JoelsElf Ok. Func is generic and this answer uses it. If you’re passing it a string, you *must* provide string for that type parameter (or constrain it to be string or a subclass of string — but string is a sealed class, so there can’t be a subclass). I wouldn’t call it pointless though — you’ve learned something.

Comment: @Joelself I actually almost created a version of this answer as I now know you want, but went with string, string as I thought it was more likely from the question. Ah well, still not pointless though, with this sort of stuff its using the defined types consistently that matters